# Is it better to embed a view controller or add a subview?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

For example, if I required a `UITableView` to appear beneath additional content in a view, would it be best practice to either:

- add a `UITableView` as a subview, or
- add a container view holding a `UITableViewController`?

As far as I know, both would provide the same user experience, however I am interested to know which method would be considered best practice?

Comment: Per view per controller will be easy to write and debug. However, you may create different model object which interacts with the same view controller such as datasource and delegate could be different object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule for iOS, especially for the iPhone/iPod touch form factor, is that you should have only one view controller on the screen at any given time. The only case I can think of when you would want to violate that guideline is when you have a subview that has a lot of logic built in to it, and the subview needs to be included in multiple other views. For example, a popover should have its own view controller because it might need to be shown in conjunction with multiple other view controllers.

In your case, I would strongly suggest just adding the UITableView as a subview unless (1) the table view has a lot of logic that isn’t related to that of the parent view controller, or (2) you will need to display the same table view in another part of your app.

Comment: I would disagree with that general rule in todays iOS. The ability to add child view controllers seems to be a move in a different direction. Here's a good article about all this: http://www.objc.io/issue-1/containment-view-controller.html

Comment: The change from the "one per screen" has already happened in the Android world. It's only question of time that the iOS world moves in this direction too if it turns out to be better. Slicing up the app into components is always a good thing to do.

Comment: @JamesRichard That’s good to know. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the discussion. I guess it's also worth mentioning that using a container view has the added benefit of supporting static UITableViewCells, which I believe are currently only available within a UITableViewController.

Answer (score 6):

You have several options:

1. Add a `UITableView` and make the containing view controller the table view's data source and delegate.
2. Add a `UITableView` and make some other class the table view's data source and delegate.
3. Create a separate view controller with the table and then add the 2nd view controller as a child view controller of 1st.

The choice depends on the appropriate division of responsibility and encapsulation.

Options 2 & 3 allow for reuse if you ever need to embed the table view in more than one view controller.

There is no simple answer to your question. It all depends on your needs, your data, and your app's structure.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use a container view controller for the following reasons:

- It can be reused in another part of the application.
- Maintains single-responsibility of the objects (Main view controller focuses on displaying information about the model, and the table view controller handles displaying information about a relationship in the model, for example).
- Keeps source files smaller and easier to read.
- Easier to build tests for.

Ultimately though, they are both valid solutions.